# Problemas con un proyecto en Arduino

Tags: arduino

Tengo un keyPad y hago la lectura de los datos que ingresa el usuario, el mismo debe estar conformado por máximo tres dígitos y no mayor al número 300.

Si ingreso el dato funciona, pero el sistema va evaluando digito por digito (En el loop) y necesito que el sistema haga una espera, colocar 1, 2 o 3 digitos y se evalúe junto, por ejemplo si ingreso en el keyPad 25 lo tome como un entero y lo lea como 25, actualmente hace el loop con el 2 y luego con el 5, ese mismo valor que está en la variable `TECLA` es un `char` cuando intento pasarlo a la variable `CANTIDAD` como `int` da error,  esto lo necesito para el `for` y el `if` que se encuentra abajo.

El `for` es un error me imagino, porque está dentro de un loop, necesito hacer una cuenta regresiva del valor ingresado, y al finalizar apagar el `LED`.

```
#include <Keypad.h>

const int ledPIN = 13;

const byte FILAS = 4;
const byte COLUMNAS = 4;
char keys [FILAS][COLUMNAS] = {
    {'1', '2', '3', 'A'},
    {'4', '5', '6', 'B'},
    {'7', '8', '9', 'C'},
    {'*', '0', '#', 'D'}
};

byte pinesFilas[FILAS] = {7, 6, 5, 4};
byte pinesColumnas[COLUMNAS] = {3, 2, 8, 0};

Keypad teclado = Keypad(makeKeymap(keys), pinesFilas, pinesColumnas, FILAS, COLUMNAS);
char TECLA;
int CANTIDAD;
byte INDICE = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(ledPIN , OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
   TECLA = teclado.getKey();
   if(TECLA) {
     CANTIDAD = TECLA.toInt();
     INDICE++;
     Serial.print(TECLA);
     digitalWrite(ledPIN , HIGH);

    for(int count=0; count<CANTIDAD; count--)
    {
      Serial.print(count);
      delay(500);
    }

    digitalWrite(ledPIN , LOW);
   }
   if(CANTIDAD > 300 or INDICE > 3){ //Aquí no puede evaluar el valor de CANTIDAD porque lo lee como un caracter y no un entero.
    Serial.println(" Excede a 300");
    INDICE = 0;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La lectura es creada tecla por tecla, no varias a la vez. por lo que debes concatenar las lecturas en una variable, antes de evaluar

```
//Primero, declara una variable para guardar

String inputString;

//Configura la variable
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(ledPIN , OUTPUT);
  inputString.reserve(3);
}

void loop() {
  char TECLA = keypad.getKey();

  if (TECLA) {
    if (TECLA >= '0' && TECLA <= '9' && INDICE<=3) {     // Permitir solo Numeros
      inputString += TECLA;               // Si es numero, se concatena
      INDICE++;
    } else if (TECLA == '#') {
      if (inputString.length() > 0) {
        CANTIDAD = inputString.toInt(); // Se convierte a numero entero
        inputString = "";               // Limpiar la variable para usar nuavemente

        // Aqui agregas lo que quieres hacer con tu codigo 

      }
    } else if (TECLA == '*') {
      inputString = "";                 // Limpiar la variable con *
    }
  }
}
```

al codigo anterior, puede eliminar el uso de * y # dejandolo automatico al digitar los tres números

Comment: Gracias, voy a intentarlo y te aviso.

Comment: Muchas gracias, era lo que necesitaba!